# How to convert a Drupal website to standalone exe file?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to convert my Drupal website to a standalone .exe file. I tried some popular applications like [ZZEE PHPExe](http://www.zzee.com/phpexe/) or [ExeOutputPHP](http://www.exeoutput.com/download.php), `ZZEE PHPExe` returns the error that `/includes/boostrap.inc` is not found in the output directory, while I copied that folder in there. The `ExeOutputPHP` errors `File not Found` and nothing else! it doesn't even tell me what file is not found!

Any suggestion to convert Drupal website to standalone exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate a static copy of your site first.

For that you can either use a module like the [static module](https://www.drupal.org/project/static), or just "copy" your entire site with wget or curl.

So for example you can do something like this :

```
wget -p --convert-links http://localhost/ -P ~/site_static_copy
```

(This assumes that you're accessing your localhost with http://localhost/ and that you want to copy under your ~/site_static_copy directory )

Once you've done that you'll be able to package the copy with the tools you mention.

Comment: I copied the website in local host, that is not enough? I also use Ajax, will that be executed?

Comment: You want to make an offline copy of your site. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: No difference does it make, an offline website in order to be able to run it with out webserver or make .exe of website

Comment: I installed Static module, it gave the warning `Couldn't create a batch, please check the batch size.` I changed the `Number of items per batch run` value but it still doesn't work. I even set its values to 1

Comment: Try doing a copy of the site with the **wget command** chown above and try compiling it with ZZEE.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying right now and let you know the result

Comment: My OS is windows7 . I installed `sed.4.2.1` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/?source=typ_redirect Is this the right application for wget?

Comment: I don't know, I'm running ubuntu. If you want an app that does the same on windows you can get HTTrack https://www.httrack.com/ . As for wget for windows I'd say try here : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: My OS is 64-bit

Comment: Try HTTrack then. You have a 64bit version for W7.  http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html

Comment: what does HTTrack  do? it provides the *wget command* ?

Comment: Same as wget but with a nice windows-like interface.

Comment: It has a few Actions, I selected the `Download all sites in pages` and it is scanning the nodes. am I doing right?

Comment: Yes that sounds right. When it's finished you can try ZZEE and provide the stuff that httrack has copied. (See your local copy under the Base Path that you provided.)

Answer (score -2):

I will suggest you to create the profile for your site and then you just need to install it all the time whenever you needed.

Comment: what do you mean `create the profile for your site` ?

Comment: Don't you know about default profile. You can create your own profile.